# Continuous function bounded in $L^\infty$

Tags: continuity, lp-spaces

Is a continuous (real-valued) function in $L^\infty$ a (everywhere-)bounded function?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous and unbounded on $\Bbb R$, say, then given any number $M$, there is a non-degenerate interval $I_M$ such that $|f(x)|>M$ for all $x\in I_M$.  From this it follows that such an $f$ is not essentially bounded; and so, not an element of $L_\infty(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Where is the function supposed to be defined?

Answer (score 2):

An arbitrary function is almost everywhere bounded because it has finite $\infty$ norm.

A continuous function will be bounded everywhere then.